# Quickly create a large file on a Mac OS X system?

Tags: macos

In order to create a 10 GB temp file...

In Linux you can do this:

```
fallocate -l 10G temp_10GB_file
```

In Windows you can do this:

```
fsutil file createnew temp_10GB_file 10000000000
```

...but what about if you're in OS X?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

macOS has the command `mkfile` to achieve the same:

```
mkfile -n 10g temp_10GB_file
```

Syntax:

```
mkfile [ -nv ] size[b|k|m|g] filename ...
```

And here's the related [manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mkfile.8.html) for `mkfile`

*Cross Platform Alternative (Unix including macOS)*:

As an alternative you could also you the Unix util `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=temp_10GB_file bs=1 count=0 seek=10G
```

Note that on macOS you need to use a lowercase for the unit as follow:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=temp_10GB_file bs=1 count=0 seek=10g
```

And here's the related [manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dd.1.html) for `dd`

Comment: mkfile is very slow :(

Comment: An advantage of using `dd` is that you can use `if=/dev/urandom` to fill the file with random data instead of zeroes. This may make the resulting file more "realistic" if you need a test file that is going to be subject to compression (e.g. download or ZIP speed test)

Comment: I cannot confirm that mkfile is slow. It's nearly instantaneous.

Comment: where will it output the file?

Comment: right in the directory where the command is executed, if the command is executed as listed above.

Comment: Why does `du [folder]` not accurately reflect the size of these files? Is this due to actual vs allocated disk usage?

Comment: How is this file creation instant? I thought it should be *filled* with the zeroes? Or does it really only contain the zeroes? Or is there another background I'm missing ? :) btw: man page for apple dd doesn't exist any more ...

Comment: To **ZIP** with ***no compression*** `zip -Z store temp_10GB_zip.zip temp_10GB_file` or `zip -0 temp_10GB_zip.zip temp_10GB_file`

Comment: Tried this on an external drive and on MacOS dd is instant, but mkfile takes a long time. Not sure how long because I waited a while and ended up just killing the process and using dd instead.

Comment: on macOS 12.6 even with if=/dev/urandom I have got the file with only zeroes

Comment: dd if=/dev/urandom of=temp_10GB_file bs=1g count=10         this works on macOS to generate random file.   took about 40 seconds on i9 macPro