# File.length greater than 8 pebibytes?

Tags: javascript, paging, bigint

How does JavaScript handle it when a `Blob` or `File` has a length greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` bytes (8 PiB; 9 PB)?

```js
let file = await filePrompt("Please upload a ten petabyte file.");
let len = file.byteLength;
for ( let i = ((len <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) ? 0 : BigInt(0)) ; i < len ; i++ ) {
    …
}
```

In the above code, for example, will `typeof len === 'bigint'`?

(I do not have access to a runtime environment with enough resources to test this.)

Comment: you have a 9 million gig file? how is that even stored?

Comment: In what context is your code running? Browser or NodeJS?

Comment: Are there actually any filesystems that are able to hold files this size? This seems like a theoretical problem that can't actually exist.

Comment: Also, think about how long that upload is going to take.

Comment: "*I do not have access to a runtime environment with enough resources to test this*" - few people will have a system where they can actually store petabytes of data. However, that shouldn't stop you from creating an empty file that just has such a humongous size: [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/982659/1048572) [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/139261/1048572) [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26796729/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi True as to the file _on-filesystem_... though I do not think FS-holes will survive the translation over to a RAM-stored `File` or `ArrayBuffer`

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude an arraybuffer… no forget it. But I don't think a `File` is keeping its contents in ram already - you have to use a `FileReader` to read it, which I would assume does read it from disk. And it should be possible to [`.stream()` it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream)…

Comment: @Bergi Alas… `dd: failed to truncate to 9007199254740992 bytes in output file '8PiB.bin': File too large`; `fallocate: fallocate failed: File too large`

Answer (score 2):

The internal representation of a [`File` `size` is an `unsigned long long`](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-size). For exposing this to JavaScript, the [WebIDL spec says](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#es-unsigned-long-long):

> The result of converting an IDL `unsigned long long` value to an
> ECMAScript value is a Number value that represents the closest numeric
> value to the `unsigned long long`, choosing the numeric value with an
> *even significand* if there are two [equally close](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type)
> values. If the `unsigned long long` is less than or equal to
> 2<sup>53</sup> − 1, then the Number will be able to represent exactly
> the same value as the `unsigned long long`.

So yes, it might lose precision. It will not produce a BigInt in those cases.

However, I am reasonably certain that most browsers will fail to open such a file in the first place, and will throw an exception instead.